# What is the model argument in the super().__init__() in the example subclassing of pymc.Model?

Tags: python, subclass, pymc

The [`pymc.Model`](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/stable/api/generated/pymc.Model.html) docs show this example:

```py
class CustomModel(Model):
    # 1) override init
    def __init__(self, mean=0, sigma=1, name=''):
        # 2) call super's init first, passing model and name
        # to it name will be prefix for all variables here if
        # no name specified for model there will be no prefix
        super().__init__(name, model)
        # now you are in the context of instance,
        # `modelcontext` will return self you can define
        # variables in several ways note, that all variables
        # will get model's name prefix

        # 3) you can create variables with the register_rv method
        self.register_rv(Normal.dist(mu=mean, sigma=sigma), 'v1', initval=1)
        # this will create variable named like '{name::}v1'
        # and assign attribute 'v1' to instance created
        # variable can be accessed with self.v1 or self['v1']

        # 4) this syntax will also work as we are in the
        # context of instance itself, names are given as usual
        Normal('v2', mu=mean, sigma=sigma)

        # something more complex is allowed, too
        half_cauchy = HalfCauchy('sigma', beta=10, initval=1.)
        Normal('v3', mu=mean, sigma=half_cauchy)

        # Deterministic variables can be used in usual way
        Deterministic('v3_sq', self.v3 ** 2)

        # Potentials too
        Potential('p1', pt.constant(1))

# After defining a class CustomModel you can use it in several
# ways

# I:
#   state the model within a context
with Model() as model:
    CustomModel()
    # arbitrary actions

# II:
#   use new class as entering point in context
with CustomModel() as model:
    Normal('new_normal_var', mu=1, sigma=0)

# III:
#   just get model instance with all that was defined in it
model = CustomModel()

# IV:
#   use many custom models within one context
with Model() as model:
    CustomModel(mean=1, name='first')
    CustomModel(mean=2, name='second')

# variables inside both scopes will be named like `first::*`, `second::*`
```

Clearly is isn't a working example, rather it is meant to give an overview of some of the internals of defining a custom PyMC model class.

I do have a question about part of this example though. When the parent class is initialized with `super().__init__(name, model)` I see there are two arguments passed: `name` and `model`. I think `name` might just be a string, but what is less clear to me is what `model` is supposed to be. Is `model` also supposed to be a string? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs you linked, `model` appears to be a module-level variable, which is set by the contextmanager:

```py
with Model() as model:  # the "as model" part, here
    CustomModel()
```

I don't know why a contextmanager is being used, but it's like doing:

```py
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = model


# just to demonstrate & FYI
try:
    Bar()  # will raise that "model" is undefined
except NameError as ex:
    print(ex)


# entering the contextmanager
model = Model()  # the "as model"
model.__enter__()

try:
    bar = Bar()  # won't raise, now that "model" is defined
except Exception as ex:
    # exiting the contextmanager that errored
    model.__exit__(type(err), err, err.__traceback__)
else:
    # exiting the contextmanager without an error
    model.__exit__(None, None, None)


assert bar.value is model  # True
```

In other words, in that example, `model` is `Model()`.

IMO the code is indeed confusing, and it would have been less confusing were it passed in as an explicit constructor arg.

Comment: Does `with Model() as model:
    CustomModel()` actually run without error for you? I get `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'items'`.

Comment: I've not run any code -- I'm just interpreting the linked example, which you've discovered is broken. What you're seeing is to be expected, based on [pymc source](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/v5.3.1/pymc/model.py#L1086). Worth submitting an issue to the pymc project about.